# Blue Prism webservice call and csv download

Tags: api, csv, rpa, blueprism

I am trying to configure Blue Prism to make an API call, and then response of this API is a csv file.

Currently I have configured the webservice with "GET" command on the base URL.
But I am not sure what needs to be done in order to download / save the csv file that the API sends. I am assuming that it needs to be explicitly told.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

In your process, make the HTTP request to the API using the `Utility - HTTP` VBO's HTTP Request action. Store the `Result` output parameter in a Text-typed Data Item.

#### If you need to process the data in a tabular format...

Once the CSV data is there, you can use the `Get CSV As Collection` action in the `Utility - Strings` VBO to parse the CSV content into a collection:

[image: screenshot]

#### If you need to simply save the file...

... use the `Utility - File Management` VBO's `Write Text File` action and point it to the location you need to save the CSV to:

[image: screenshot]